# Cant fetch token after login

Tags: angular

The code is supposed to login the user by email and password through an API and then and fetch access token but it doesn't. In the local storage there is no token. When I enter the wrong password it shows error in console with status: 401, and when i enter correct password it doesn't show any error, also in the network tab status is 200 for the request with correct password, so I think its logging in but not fetching the token.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login1',
  templateUrl: './login1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login1.component.css']
})
export class Login1Component implements OnInit {
loggedIn = false;
loginForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private api: ApiService, private route: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const user = {
      email: this.loginForm.controls.email.value,
      password: this.loginForm.controls.password.value
    };

    this.api.loginUser(user);
    this.api.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( (val) => {
      this.loggedIn = val;
      this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    });

  }

}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  checkStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isUserLoggedIn = this.checkStatus.asObservable();

  readonly loginUrl= 'https://*************';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  checkLogin() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if(token) {
      this.checkStatus.next(true);
    } else {
      this.checkStatus.next(false);
    }
  }

  loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
    .subscribe((checkUser: any) => {
      if(checkUser.access_token) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', checkUser.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(checkUser.user));
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: try using `this.loggedIn = val.valueOf();` to coerce it back to a primitive from the `Observable`.

Answer (score 2):

You code seems fine. Naive question, have you checked if your API is sending back properly "checkUser.access_token" and that it's not undefined?

Moreover, local storage is not a recommended place to store auth tokens.

> Browser local storage (or session storage) is not secure. Any data
>   stored there may be vulnerable to cross-site scripting. If an attacker
>   steals a token, they can gain access to and make requests to your API.

Usually when dealing with SPA, you would use in memory. Cookies are also an option with some limitations and attention points. If you're using node.js/express as backend I would recommend the use of https://github.com/expressjs/session as it extremely helps with setting sessions access tokens in a secure way.

Regarding store tokens I would recommend this reading: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

Comment: So perhaps you should check for "if(checkUser.success.token)" and set "localStorage.setItem('access_token', checkUser.success.token);".  Am I missing something?

Comment: If the token is stored in memory and not in the browser's local storage, what happens when a spa webpage is reloaded? The in memory data is wiped out... Thus the user needs to login again?

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest secure method but not most effective way definitely. It's sometimes a viable solution because, depending on the way you build, SPAs are actually not meant to be reloaded. When building bigger apps you could use sessions(server side sessions and tokenid) or JWT(client side auth), but they are more complex than simply storing it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for loginUser before trying to access token

```
this.api.loginUser(user).subscribe(() => {
    this.api.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe( (val) => {
      this.loggedIn = val;
      this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    });
});
```

To be honest I don't even see the point of subscribing to isUserLoggedIn. Instead you could use the value returned in loginUser method

```
this.api.loginUser(user).subscribe((val) => {
   this.loggedIn = val;
   if (val) {
      this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
   }
});
```